# React native firebase - facebook sign-in

Tags: firebase, facebook, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Im following the [official code sample](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth) provided by RNFB....code below

Problem is that you dont get past the line `const facebookCredential = firebase.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);`.....it appears that the `firebase.FacebookAuthProvider` method is showing as undefined so you dont get the `facebookCredential` variable back

```
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

async function onFacebookButtonPress() {
  // Attempt login with permissions
  const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);

  if (result.isCancelled) {
    throw 'User cancelled the login process';
  }

  // Once signed in, get the users AccesToken
  const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

  if (!data) {
    throw 'Something went wrong obtaining access token';
  }

  // Create a Firebase credential with the AccessToken
  const facebookCredential = auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);

  // Sign-in the user with the credential
  return auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
}
```

Comment: Did you try `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider`? Because in your example, auth seems to be undefined. (The same issues seems to be there in the example)

Comment: yes that worked - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example linked seems to be missing the declaration of an `auth` variable. We need to get it from the imported `firebase` moduled.

Instead of:

`auth.FacebookAuthProvider`

We should be using:

`firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider`